# SSIS Foreach loop container dynamic file name and path, exclude file with more than a certain underscore

Tags: ssis

I have a Foreach File Enumerator that will read pdf files name from a folder and place the filename into database. However, i wan it to exclude reading filename that has more less than 3 underscore.

```
AAA_BBB_000004554_060420161906_S1234567H_M.pdf
AAA_BBB_000003345_060420161906_S9876543H_S.pdf
AAA_BBB_000008546_060420161906_S1234123H_V.pdf
AAA_BBB_201604.pdf  
etc
```

AAA_BBB_201604.pdf should be excluded in the loop as the filename only has 2 underscore.

How can i archive that? i did some search and it seems like using expression is the key, but i had no idea how to do it. Kindly help thank you.

Comment: If the filenames are consistent you could use a suitable filename filter, i.e. `???_???_?????????_*.PDF` would include your example filenames and exclude your example. I suggest you just run a DOS ROBOCOPY copy command beforehand that identifies and moves suitable files, as long as they can be identified by a suitable pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690414(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using TOKENCOUNT function in an Expression.

Create 2 variables

1. FileName of String type
2. TokenCount of Int32 type

Foreach Loop Container

3. Use Foreach Loop Container and set the Collection - Foreach File
   Enumerator
4. Specify the folder location where your .pdf files exists
5. set ".pdf* under Files: Select the radio button Retrieve File Name -
   Name only

[image]

6. Map the File Name retrieved

[image]

7. Next, put an **Expression** task inside the Foreach Loop Container and using the following expression
8. Next, drop an Execute SQL Task and connect it from Expression task

   `@[User::TokenCount]  = TOKENCOUNT( @[User::FileName]  ,"_")`

   This uses the TOKENCOUNT function - Returns the number of tokens in a string (FileName in your case)   that contains tokens separated by the specified delimiters ('_' in your case)

   Assign the token count to an int variable - @[User::TokenCount]
9. In the Precedence constraint Editor, provide the following Constraint Options

[image]

10. Configure the Execute SQL Task

[image]

11. Finally, it should like this

[image]

12. I put script task between Expression task and Execute SQL task for debugging purpose, if you want you my use this

[image]

13. Running the package - let's say you want to load these file names from this folder

    [image]
14. Since, we gave the condition in the expression (Token count > 3), after running the package, these file names will be loading in the database

[image]

Hope this helps.